# change color of scroll bar indicator in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

How can I change color of scroll bar indicator in `SingleChildScrollView`, the `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't have option color or something for style, if we can't change color of `SingleChildScrollView` do we have any alternative for that

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScrollbarTheme-class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RawScrollbar(
    thumbColor: Colors.red,
    radius: Radius.circular(16),
    thickness: 7,
    child: SingleChildScrollView()
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can provide `ScrollbarThemeData:thumbColor` by wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
 Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
    thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
  )),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
```

[image]